# How check that all files successfully download from server by GEB, Selenium, Groovy

Tags: http, selenium, groovy, geb

How i can check that all files successfully download from server by GEB, Selenium or Groovy ?
All files are available and has status Code:200 OK in the head  of the http/https request ?
....or simply understand that i have downloaded without error